# Uno Platform Material Card

Tags: material-ui, uno-platform

I am trying to use the card from the Material design that Uno has added.  However- when I followed the example- the card would not appear.  I am using the bottomNavigationBar from Material elsewhere in the app and it is working fine.  As a note- I saw one example with Header and one with HeaderContent.  I have tried both and neither worked.  Nothing is displayed at all- IOS or Android.  What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

```
<Page
    x:Class="sampleApp.Shared.Views.appCardPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:sampleApp.Shared.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:material="using:Uno.Material.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{StaticResource SubPageBackground}" >

        <material:Card HeaderContent="Outlined card"
           SubHeaderContent="With title and subitle"
           Style="{StaticResource MaterialOutlinedCardStyle}" />
        
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<material:Card HeaderContent="Outlined card"
               SubHeaderContent="With title and subtitle only"
               Style="{StaticResource MaterialOutlinedCardStyle}">
   <material:Card.HeaderContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                    Margin="16,14,16,0"
                    Style="{ThemeResource MaterialHeadline6}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </material:Card.HeaderContentTemplate>
   <material:Card.SubHeaderContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                    Margin="16,0,16,14"
                    Style="{ThemeResource MaterialBody2}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </material:Card.SubHeaderContentTemplate>
</material:Card>
```

It seems `HeaderContentTemplate` and `SubHeaderContentTemplate` don't have a default value in the `MaterialOutlinedCardStyle` style, that could be improved.

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Themes/issues/536

Comment: I gave that a try- and it is still not displaying.  Just to check on things- I tested putting in a bottomNavBar- and it worked on the same page with no problems.  I did try reverting to an earlier version of Uno.Material(I am using 674- went to 637) and that did not help either.   I dont think I need to do this- but do I need to overwrite any of the styles in your sample?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, it's curious. Uno.Material is demo'd in https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Gallery you could take a look there and try to find a difference. UnoGallery is also published as an app on ios and android, and at gallery.platform.uno

Comment: I did take a look at the Gallery- and tried that- but still not getting anywhere.  I agree- it's curious- especially given the fact it is in the Gallery App.  I really appreciate your quick responses- thank you.  Hopefully- a solution can be figured out- I can do a custom control- but I prefer the card.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Did you also need to define the two templates as described in my answer or your shorter xaml worked?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  It does work with the shorter XAML- partially.  It displays- but all the text is the same size- and no longer formatted.  So- I am sticking with the templates in my code- at least till when/if they Uno.Material is updated.  Thank you for opening the issue.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some further testing- and it turns out in my app.xaml.cs I was not initializing the material theme correctly.  I changed it to what is in the example found here: [Uno Material Documentation](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Themes/blob/master/README.md)

In section 3.  What was really interesting is the bottomNavigationBar I use from Material worked in spite of all of this.  Hopefully this will help someone else that has a similar issue.